# Which Scala framework for building a REST API with a Cassandra back-end would you suggest?

Tags: scala, rest, api, cassandra, nosql

I want to build a REST API with a Cassandra backend in Scala but since there are many frameworks available and some have limitations for NoSQL databases, I'd like to know what would the better framework choices be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use a framework for a simple REST API. Simply too large, too much overhead. But the most frameworks exported their JSON libraries:

Spray: https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Lift: https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/

Play: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson

And lightweight http server:

spray: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-http/

scalatra: http://www.scalatra.org/

> some have limitations for NoSQL databases

There are no limitations. You can simply use phantom in your framework or server: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom

The documentation is a bit "clean", but you can find here a nice example: https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom

Do you need the API for internal use or as external API? If you use this API only as internal API, it's better to use another protocol like protobuf or Thrift instead of HTTP with JSON. Less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Lift](http://liftweb.net) as a flexible and powerful framework for web related stuff. There are a few nice helper tools for building HTTP api: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-11.html

Lift comes with some ORM built-in, but you can skip them and use whatever database solution you wish. I personally used Lift both with MongoDB and the casbah driver, and PostgreSQL with Slick.